# Update a column with different values in each row

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update

Each row of the column id_location has a diferent value.
I've tried this so far:

```
UPDATE Apartment  
         Join Location 
         On
         Apartment.id_location= Location.id_location;
        SET Apartment.state = Location.state;
```

thank you.
Note: id_location is a FK coming From Location (where id_lcoation is a PK). Also, I can not use the INSERT INTO because it takes sooo much time. I am also using postgres

Comment: Please provide more details about the problem? Are you seeing an error with the update that you are using? It is also odd that an insert is slower than an update

Answer (score 0):

Postgres has its own particular syntax for doing an update join:

```
UPDATE Apartment a
SET state = l.state
FROM Location l
WHERE a.id_location= l.id_location;
```

You could also use a correlated subquery to do the update:

```
UPDATE Apartment a
SET state = (SELECT l.state FROM Location l WHERE a.id_location= l.id_location)
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 FROM Location l WHERE a.id_location= l.id_location);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tim is correct about the syntax.

However, you should fix your data model.  You should not be repeating the state in two different tables.  Instead, you can look up the `state` when needed:

```
select a.*, l.state
from apartment a join
     location l
     using (id_location);
```

This *guarantees* that the "apartment" is always in the correct state that the location suggests.

If this information is often needed, use a view:

```
create view v_apartments as
    select a.*, l.state
    from apartment a join
         location l
         using (id_location);
```